# How to enable/allow java to run in a CefSharp application

Tags: c#, wpf, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

We are making a web browser to experiment with Oracle's ADT/Forms technology. All it needs to do is go to the web address and run the Java applet.

I'm using (trying to, at least) CefSharp3 (fresh clone from https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp).

I created a WPF project for this, got it working (I can navigate to Google, here, Oracle, etc) however, when I navigate  to our Java applet I seem to get nothing but a blank screen.

I have set browser-attributes

- "JavaDisabled"
- "PluginsDisabled"
- "WebSecurityDisabled"

(grasping at straws there!) appropriately and still I only see a blank screen.

I'm wondering if maybe the app does not have permissions to the JRE? Maybe the JRE needs to be included in the project?

This is the result of the Debug file (after a fresh run that ONLY goes to the Java applet)

```
[1011/121439:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(280)] locale_file_path.empty()
[1011/121439:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(280)] locale_file_path.empty()
[1011/121439:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(280)] locale_file_path.empty()
[1011/121439:ERROR:renderer_main.cc(226)] Running without renderer sandbox
[1011/121441:WARNING:content_browser_client.cc(480)] No browser info matching view process id 3 and routing id 2
[1011/121441:WARNING:content_browser_client.cc(480)] No browser info matching view process id 3 and routing id 2
[1011/121441:WARNING:content_browser_client.cc(480)] No browser info matching view process id 3 and routing id 2
[1011/121441:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(280)] locale_file_path.empty()
[1011/121441:WARNING:content_browser_client.cc(480)] No browser info matching view process id 3 and routing id 2
[1011/121441:WARNING:content_browser_client.cc(480)] No browser info matching view process id 3 and routing id 2
[1011/121441:WARNING:content_browser_client.cc(480)] No browser info matching view process id 3 and routing id 2
```

The Java applet works no problem in Firefox, Chrome, IE, and Chromium (with WinForms). It could just be that WPF and Java don't jive.

Here's some code! -- it's not much, but it doesn't take much to use this framework -- I AM quite impressed.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow() {

        InitializeCef();
        InitializeComponent();
        SetBrowserSettings();

        ((IWebBrowser)webBrowser).Load("URL_To_Java_Applet");
    }

    private void InitializeCef() {
        var settings = new CefSharp.CefSettings()
        {
            PackLoadingDisabled = true
        };
        settings.IgnoreCertificateErrors = true; // could be preventing the JRE?
        Cef.Initialize(settings);
    }

    private void SetBrowserSettings() {
        BrowserSettings settings = new BrowserSettings();
        settings.JavaDisabled = false;
        settings.PluginsDisabled = false;
        settings.WebSecurityDisabled = true; // desperate attempt to allow JRE to run!
        webBrowser.BrowserSettings = settings;
    }
}
```

Comment: What CefSharp version? Any errors in debug.log? What kind of url is it, a local file or http, if it's a local file have you tried uploading it to web and run from there? Does google.com url load fine? Any errors in DevTools?

Comment: @CzarekTomczak great questions! -- I should have anticipated them. I will update my question with the information you're looking for.

Comment: `locale_file_path.empty()` warning - looks like you're missing some of the binaries. Do locales/ directory and .pak files reside next to the executable?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're right...

> It could just be that WPF and Java don't jive.

Try with WinForms, not WPF where prospects doesn't look good (note WPF run in OSR mode)

See this [CEF forum thread](http://www.magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=602)

**update:** I tried with http://java.com/en/download/installed8.jsp and Win32 builds of CefSharp.Winforms|Wpf.Example - they both work as expected with JRE 7.67 x86. Of course the x64 Examples didn't work as I don't have a x64 JRE on my PC.